# TwentyFifteen: How can it show a different color on every post page?

Tags: customization, css, theme-twenty-fifteen

I have made a child theme of TwentyFifteen. 
Am trying to set on styles.css of the child theme a specific color on every page or post.

I tried somethin like that

```
.post-id-no.id .hentry,.site-footer {
background-color: #RGBColor !important;
}
```

But I didn't see any difference, its still white. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS code syntax is not correct. For post and page specific CSS, you need to use something like this:

```
/* Replace x with post/page id and post with page and vice versa*/ 
.page-id-x .hentry, 
.page-id-x .entry-footer {
   background-color: #RGBColor !important;
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the quick answer, but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Give me your URL link.

Comment: @Alex Did you replace x with your post id?

Comment: It should be `.page-id-35 .hentry` I just added the code and it works. Where are you adding your CSS?

Comment: on child css file

Comment: I have updated the code, use them.

Comment: still doesn't work :/

Comment: CSS cache issue? Clean your cache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23697/discussion-between-alex-and-manoj-kumar).